Matrix representation of linear transformations with respect to different basis
Let there be some linear transformation $T:\mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^m$ with $\beta$, $\gamma$ being the bases of $\mathbb{F}^n$ and $\mathbb{F}^m$ respectively. Then, $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$ is the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $\beta$ and $\gamma$. However, if $\beta’$ and $\gamma’$ are also bases, then $[T]_{\beta’}^{\gamma’}$ is also another matrix representation of T. Clearly, though, these two are different matrices, so how should I interpret the fact that they both represent the same matrix?
Moreover, if $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the standard bases of their respective vector spaces, then $T(x)=[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}x \ \forall x\in\mathbb{F}^n$. Since left multiplication by some matrix $A$ is uniquely defined by $A$, $T(x)\neq[T]_{\beta’}^{\gamma’}x$ even though $[T]_{\beta’}^{\gamma’}$ is also a matrix representation of $T$. How, then, should I interpret $[T]_{\beta’}^{\gamma’}x$?

They represent the same linear transformation, not the same matrix. You change the basis, then the representational matrix should also be changed.

You might be less confused if you also wrote $[x]^\beta$ for the representation of the vector $x$ in the $\beta$-basis. The $x$'s on the different sides of you equation then would not be the same.

$\newcommand{\coloneqq}{\mathrel{\vcenter{:}}=}$
Consider two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over the field $\mathbb F$.
You have a linear transformation $T \mathrel{\vcenter{:}}V\to W$. Let $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)$ and $\gamma=(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_m)$ be two bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively. We use the notation $[v]_\beta$ for the coordinates of a vector $v\in V$ wrt the basis $\beta$, that is
$$[v]_\beta=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\overset{\textrm{def}}{\iff}v=x_1\beta_1+\dots+x_n\beta_n.$$
Note that the components $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ of $\beta$ are elements of $V$, while the components $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of $[v]_\beta$ are elements of $\mathbb F$.
We use the notation $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ for the matrix representation of $T$  wrt the basis $\beta$ and $\gamma$, that is
$$[T]_\beta^\gamma = A \overset{\textrm{def}}{\iff} [T(v)]_\gamma=A[v]_\beta,\:\forall v\in V.$$
Now back to your question. What is $[T]_{\beta'}^{\gamma'}x$? Trivially, $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ are the coordinates wrt the basis $\beta'$ of the vector $x_1\beta'_1+\dots+x_n\beta'_n$. Thus, we get
\begin{align}
[T]_{\beta'}^{\gamma'}x&=[T]_{\beta'}^{\gamma'}[x_1\beta'_1+\dots+x_n\beta'_n]_{\beta'}\\&=[T(x_1\beta'_1+\dots+x_n\beta'_n)]_{\gamma'}.
\end{align}
The last equality follows from the definition of $[T]_{\beta'}^{\gamma'}$.
In summary, $[T]_{\beta'}^{\gamma'}x$ are the coordinates wrt the basis $\gamma'$ of the vector $T(x_1\beta'_1+\dots+x_n\beta'_n)$.

You’ve explained how to find the matrix representation of a linear algebra, which I know how to do. However, you didn’t really answer my question, which is what the matrix representation does not in the standard basis when you left multiply it to a vector
